# Why `San Bruno, CA` != `San Bruno, CA`?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

For some reason, `San Bruno, CA` means `Sheridan, MT` on Careers 2.0.

- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/applyonly?location=san+bruno%2C+california — San Bruno, CA.
- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/applyonly?location=san+bruno%2C+ca — Sheridan, MT.

Comment: Ah yes, the ever elusive careers location bugs, we meet again...

Comment: Ah crap, did San Bruno move *again*?

Comment: @Nick I keep telling you not to mess with the "country locations" SQL table, but you didn't listen, did you? One day you're going to cause an earthquake or something. ;)

Comment: @Doorknob I'm not entirely sure this is Nick's *fault*.

Comment: @Doorknob Your supposition stands on _shaky_ ground. You might cause a _rift_ in your otherwise well-intentioned friendship.

Comment: @Richard no it's actually Popular Demand's fault! [See for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No satisfying answer I’m afraid, spurious data. I’ve cleared the cache, looks better now.

Comment: yeap, seems to work now; really weird how it goes like that; what i found funny is that "san bruno, california" does show up as "San Bruno, CA", so, it's weird that "San Bruno, CA" itself would take you to a totally unrelated place!