# Ability to see why our edit was rejected

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Can we add the ability to see why a suggested edit we made was rejected?

For example, on the question "[Why `San Bruno, CA` != `San Bruno, CA`?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178718/why-san-bruno-ca-san-bruno-ca)", I fixed up the question and changed its title to a more ask why "San Bruno, CA" isn't equal to "San Bruno, California", as evident by the links the OP provided.

After a few minutes, the notice that my edit is only visible to me disapeared and the question remained the same. I figured this was rejected as "Too Minor" for some reason, but I would like to know why.

Again, can we add the ability to see *why* an edit we made was rejected? It would also help new users learn that don't know to read the FAQ know what edits are [supposed to be] allowed, and what isn't. Maybe a notification [in the top left]?

---

**LET THE DOWNVOTING COMMENCE!**

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13974: The OP rejected your edit.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, yes. But I'm asking if we can add a link somewhere that will take you _to_ that review page. Now, how is that an incorrect edit or attempt to reply to the post?

Comment: The link is on your profile: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186285/cole-johnson?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: @Mysticial The only link is the link to the question (_suggested edit on Why `San Bruno, CA` != `San Bruno, CA`?_)

Comment: The "suggest edit" text is the link.

Comment: I've marked the edit as incorrect, because you've attempted to impose your own way of how the information in the question is to be conveyed; you've basically only edited the question to convert it to your own personal and subjective style, not to fix any apparent issues, and I strongly disagree with the style you've tried to impose → hence an incorrect edit classification.  Besides, `San Bruno, California` does show up as `San Bruno, CA` on Careers 2.0, so your suggested title is wrong, period, because it completely changes the meaning.

Comment: @cnst That's what the query string said. Also, I wasn't converting it to my "own personal and subjective style". I took what was there and made it look better. I used the URL's as a reference of the query string used and converted the dumped link to a titled link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always see all your suggestions from your profile.

Go to [Your profile -> *activity* -> *suggestions*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186285/cole-johnson?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Here you can see the list of your suggestions. Clicking on particular suggestion (*suggested edit*), you will be redirected to the review page of that suggestions.

Comment: It is a horrible way to check, though. We have to open each of the suggested edit to check whether it is accepted or rejected.

Comment: @nhahtdh - Yeah there is a feature request for that. But I am not able to find out that right now.

Comment: @hims056 was this the [meta-tag:feature-request]? [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Actually that feature request is for notification. While I am searching for a request for rejection reason in the [activity tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186285/cole-johnson?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: @hims056 my mistake.  Thought it would do almost the same thing since the reason would/could be shown in the notification.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Yeah that's true.

Comment: @hims056 Just found [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history) linked to the notification question

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Yes that feature request will help users to find the reason easily. I was searching for the same. Thank you.